# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'WindowsCodePage' on 'System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding'

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to serialize Windows-1252 encoding, coming from package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, to JSON. Unfortunately, I get error "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'WindowsCodePage' on 'System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding'" when trying to do so. Everything works correctly for other encoding (Encoding.UTF8).

Code to reproduce:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        var workingEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        var notWorkingEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
        
        Console.WriteLine(workingEncoding.EncodingName);
        Console.WriteLine(notWorkingEncoding.EncodingName);
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        var workingSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(workingEncoding);
        Console.WriteLine(workingSerialized);
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        var notWorkingSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notWorkingEncoding);
        Console.WriteLine(notWorkingSerialized);
    }
}
```

Example fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/P2qS7z

Has anyone encountered a similar issue and have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any idea how to do it in a different way, I ended up doing a workaround and created a DTO `EncodingDetails` which has same public fields as "Encoding" class from System.Text, and extension methods for mapping one to another:

```
public static class EncodingExtensions
{
    public static EncodingDetails ToEncodingDetails(this Encoding encoding)
    {
        var serializerSettings = CreateJsonSettingsSuppressingErrors();

        var serializedEncoding = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(encoding, serializerSettings);
        var deserializedDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EncodingDetails>(serializedEncoding);

        return deserializedDetails;
    }

    private static JsonSerializerSettings CreateJsonSettingsSuppressingErrors()
    {
        return new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Error = (_, args) => args.ErrorContext.Handled = true
        };
    }

    public static Encoding GetEncoding(this EncodingDetails encodingDetails)
    {
        return Encoding.GetEncoding(encodingDetails.CodePage);
    }
}
```

During serialization I suppress all errors and save values only for those properties that are possible to be serialized.

During deserialization, I use `Encoding.GetEncoding` and provide serialized CodePage, to get the original Encoding from .NET.

If anyone comes across any better solution, feel free to share it. For now I will mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the encoding `windows-1252` is not available in the `.NET` environments.

This encoding belongs to the Windows platform, but not on other platforms like `Linux` or `macOS`.

If you are running the code in `non-windows` machine, that is why you are getting the error.

Comment: I am testing it also on Windows machine, same error. The encoding is not supported by .net core by default, but as far as I read, adding nuget "System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" should add support for that. It looks more like this encoding, registered with "Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)", is missing value in some field (WindowsCodePage) which causes serialization to fail

Comment: note that creating a file with this encoding works correctly. It's only a problem of serialization of the "Encoding" object itself